# Copy/paste coordinates in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Is there a way how to copy/paste both coordinates in Inkscape? At this moment, if I want to say, place two circles over each other, I copy/paste x coordinate, than copy/paste y coordinate.

I was wondering wherther I can do it more efficiently, I am newbie to Inkscape

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) software

Comment: Perhaps is faster use the align tool

Comment: "Paste in Place" will paste at the same coordinates as where it was copied.